# RestAPI and Neo4j

Tags: heroku, neo4j

Can anyone help with these Neo4j (1.9) errors and the RestApi using JDK 1.6 and Heroku.

The objective of the code is only to demo the functionality of using cypher and Neo4j with Java. I understand that only the RestAPI works at Heroku.

```
package com.example;

import java.util.List;

import org.neo4j.graphdb.Direction;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.GraphDatabaseService;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Node;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Relationship;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.RelationshipType;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Transaction;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory;
import org.neo4j.helpers.collection.*;
import org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.RestAPI;
import org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.RestAPIFacade;
import org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.RestGraphDatabase;
import org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.query.RestCypherQueryEngine;
import org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.util.*;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import java.util.Map;


 import com.example.IDatabaseConnector;
//import org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.RestGraphDatabase;
//import org.neo4j.

@Component
//public class Neo4jDatabaseConnector implements IDatabaseConnector {
public class Neo4jDatabaseConnector implements IDatabaseConnector{

    Node aNode;
    Node first;
    Node second;
    Relationship relation;
    private static GraphDatabaseService GraphDb;
    private static RestAPI restAPI;
    Transaction txn;

    private static enum RelTypes implements RelationshipType
    {
        KNOWS,
        USAGE
    }

    public void showNode( )
    {

        // have to add code for cypher
        RestCypherQueryEngine rcqe = new RestCypherQueryEngine(restAPI);
        //Then just execute your cypher statements using rcqe.query().
     // int length=0;
        String countNodes = "START n=node(*) RETURN count(*)";
        String createNodes = "CREATE (n {name: 'Trevor Oakley'})";
         rcqe.query(createNodes, null);


     // QueryResult <Map<String,Object>> result = rcqe.query(countNodes, null);

        //for  (Map<String, Object> row:result){
        //  length++;   
        //}
        //System.out.println("length="+length);


     // rcqe.query(countNodes, Map<String, Object> row:result);
        //  rcqe.query(countNodes, Map<String,Object>:result)
        //  rcqe.
/*   ExecutionEngine engine = new ExecutionEngine(GraphDb);
        int length=-1;
        try{
            ExecutionResult result = engine.execute("start n=node(*) return n");
            if (result == null){
                length = 0;
            } else
            {
                for (@SuppressWarnings("unused")
                    Map<String, Object> row:result){
                        length++;   
                    }
            }
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        //  _log.error(e.getMessage(),e);
            length=-2;
        }

         System.out.println("len="+length);
         */

    }

    public Neo4jDatabaseConnector() {
        //GraphDb=new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase(Neo4j_DBPath);
    }
    public int createDBRest()
    {
         restAPI = new RestAPIFacade(System.getenv("NEO4J_URL"), 
                   System.getenv("NEO4J_USERNAME"), 
                   System.getenv("NEO4J_PASSWORD"));
        try{
              GraphDb = new RestGraphDatabase(restAPI);
        }
            catch (Exception e){
                    return 1;
            }

           return 0;
    }
    public int createDB(String dbLoc) {

        System.out.println("db loc ="+dbLoc);
        int error = 0;
try{

        GraphDb=new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase(dbLoc); 
    //GraphDb=new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabaseBuilder(dbLoc);
        System.out.println("db loc ="+dbLoc);
        String  stringDB = GraphDb.toString();
        System.out.println("connection  ="+stringDB);
}
catch (Exception e){
    System.out.println("error - ");
    error = 1;
}
    return erro

r;
    }

Problem accessing /hello. Reason:

        Error reading as JSON ''
    Caused by:

    java.lang.RuntimeException: Error reading as JSON ''
        at org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.util.JsonHelper.readJson(JsonHelper.java:57)
        at org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.util.JsonHelper.jsonToSingleValue(JsonHelper.java:62)
        at org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.RequestResult.toEntity(RequestResult.java:114)
        at org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.RequestResult.toMap(RequestResult.java:120)
        at org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.ExecutingRestRequest.toMap(ExecutingRestRequest.java:187)
        at org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.ExecutingRestAPI.query(ExecutingRestAPI.java:475)
        at org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.ExecutingRestAPI.query(ExecutingRestAPI.java:495)
        at org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.RestAPIFacade.query(RestAPIFacade.java:233)
        at org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.query.RestCypherQueryEngine.query(RestCypherQueryEngine.java:50)
        at com.example.Neo4jDatabaseConnector.showNode(Neo4jDatabaseConnector.java:53)
        at com.example.HelloServlet.doGet(HelloServlet.java:22)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:565)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:479)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:119)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:521)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:227)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1031)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:406)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:186)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:965)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:117)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:111)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:349)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:449)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:910)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:634)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:230)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:76)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:609)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:45)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:599)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:534)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
    Caused by: java.io.EOFException: No content to map to Object due to end of input
        at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._initForReading(ObjectMapper.java:2775)
        at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:2718)
        at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:1863)
        at org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.util.JsonHelper.readJson(JsonHelper.java:55)
        ... 34 more
    Caused by:

    java.io.EOFException: No content to map to Object due to end of input
        at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._initForReading(ObjectMapper.java:2775)
        at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:2718)
        at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:1863)
        at org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.util.JsonHelper.readJson(JsonHelper.java:55)
        at org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.util.JsonHelper.jsonToSingleValue(JsonHelper.java:62)
        at org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.RequestResult.toEntity(RequestResult.java:114)
        at org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.RequestResult.toMap(RequestResult.java:120)
        at org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.ExecutingRestRequest.toMap(ExecutingRestRequest.java:187)
        at org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.ExecutingRestAPI.query(ExecutingRestAPI.java:475)
        at org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.ExecutingRestAPI.query(ExecutingRestAPI.java:495)
        at org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.RestAPIFacade.query(RestAPIFacade.java:233)
        at org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.query.RestCypherQueryEngine.query(RestCypherQueryEngine.java:50)
        at com.example.Neo4jDatabaseConnector.showNode(Neo4jDatabaseConnector.java:53)
        at com.example.HelloServlet.doGet(HelloServlet.java:22)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:565)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:479)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:119)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:521)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:227)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1031)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:406)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:186)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:965)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:117)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:111)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:349)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:449)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:910)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:634)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:230)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:76)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:609)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:45)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:599)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:534)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
```

Comment: Can you please clean up your code? It is currently not clear which parts are actively called and which not. In general the RestAPI / RestGraphDatabase part looks kind of ok. What is your NEO4J_URL ? Can you check with `heroku config` if the environment variables are correctly set?

Comment: public void showNode( )
 {
 
  
     restAPI = new RestAPIFacade(System.getenv("NEO4J_URL"), 
         System.getenv("NEO4J_USERNAME"), 
         System.getenv("NEO4J_PASSWORD"));
   
   GraphDb = new RestGraphDatabase(restAPI);
  
  RestCypherQueryEngine rcqe = new RestCypherQueryEngine(restAPI);
 
     rcqe.query(createNodes, null);
   
   
 
  
 }
 
 
 
 

 public void shutdown () {
  GraphDb.shutdown();
   
 }

}

Comment: IRON_CACHE_PROJECT_ID:          xxx
IRON_CACHE_TOKEN:               rWr-xxx
JAVA_OPTS:                      -Xmx384m -Xss512k -XX:+UseCompressedOops
MAVEN_OPTS:                     -Xmx384m -Xss512k -XX:+UseCompressedOops
NEO4J_URL:                      http://xxx@xxx.hosted.neo4j.org:7489
PATH:                           /app/.jdk/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
REDISCLOUD_URL:                 redis://rediscloud:xxx@pub-redis-15110.us-east-1-2.3.ec2.garantiadata.com:15110
TREASURE_DATA_API_KEY:          xxx

Comment: http://cd9af3706.hosted.neo4j.org:7489/webadmin/

Comment: OK the immediate error was solved now and the issue was that the password and username in the getenv were empty. The solution was to code them from the URL. I will add the code in a new answer.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was to fill the user and password fields as shown below, in terms of the immediate error.

```
String neo4jURL = System.getenv("NEO4J_URL");
        String user="user";
        String password="password";

        try{
        URL url = new URL(neo4jURL);
        String userInfo = url.getUserInfo();
        String[] userDetails = userInfo.split(":");
        user = userDetails[0];
        password = userDetails[1];

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        //
        }
```